# Nuxt this.$route is undefined

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuefire, vuexfire

I have a dynamic route called products/_id which should load an product from Firestore. I am using VueFire to fetch the product from the Firebase database. Fetching the whole products collection works perfectly fine.

```
firestore: {
    product: firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("products")
}
```

But getting the document with a certain id is where the trouble begins. Normally I would call

```
firestore: {
    product: firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("products")
      .doc(this.$route.params.id),
  }
```

But now I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined". Which is strange because if i log the route to the console I can actually see the id. Moreover, calling ".doc("DOCUMENT_ID") work perfectly fine.

Anyone knows how to fix this? I've tried a combination of methods and mounted hooks to retrieve the id but to no avail.

```
  mounted() {
    this.getProduct();
  },
  methods: {
    getProductId() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },
  },
  firestore: {
    products: firebase.firestore().collection("products").doc(this.getProductId),
  }
```

Brings up the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firestore` is specified as an object here, so it's evaluated immediately outside the context of the component, so `this` would not be the Vue component instance.

To resolve this, specify `firestore` as a function that returns the intended object, as shown in [the docs](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#firestore-option):

```js
export default {
  firestore() {
    // ✅ `this` is Vue component instance inside function
    return {
      products: firebase.firestore().collection("products").doc(this.getProductId),
    }
  }
}
```